# Difference between tableView.cellForRow(at:) and tableView.dataSource?tableView(tableView:cellForRowAt:)

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, uitableview

I'm unit testing on a `tableView` whether it renders a cell.

And I found that `tableView.cellForRow(at:)` returns nil, while `tableView.dataSource?tableView(tableView:cellForRowAt:)` returns the right cell.

Here's my unit test code.

```
it("renders one option text") {
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)

    let cell = sut.tableView.dataSource?.tableView(sut.tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath)

    let cell2 = sut.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)

    expect(cell?.textLabel?.text).toEventually(equal("A1"))  // test suceeded
    expect(cell2?.textLabel?.text).toEventually(equal("A1")) // test failed
}
```

So I'm curious about the difference of the two methods.

Apple's document says that `tableView.cellForRow(at:)` returns nil if the cell is not visible, so I'v understood that `tableView.cellForRow(at:)` returns nil when it's under unit testing,
but I'm not sure the **time order of the two methods being called** and **when `tableView.cellForRow(at:)` get the right value(cell)**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

This method is used to generate or dequeue the cells as required by tableView. This is not the UITableView member method. Instead, it is a protocol method and another object, which will be a data source, will implement and return the value. So it will always return a cell whether we are unit testing or while debugging the app.

```
tableView.cellForRow(at:)
```

This method is not the generator method. It is a member method of UITableView as a utility method for eg. for getting selected row we use tableView.selectedRow. So it is supposed to return cell for any indexPath.

As we know UITableView doesn't create cells equal to rows drawn. Suppose you wanted to draw 100 rows then UITableView only create few extra cells apart from cells which are visible. So if you pass any indexPath which is not among the visible rows then practically that cell doesn't exist. Because tableview is waiting for you to scroll and reuse the unused cells. So whether you are doing unit testing or working on app it will always show nil for cells which are not visible.

Answer (score 1):

`tableView.dataSource?tableView(tableView:cellForRowAt:)` will always dequeue a new cell.  It isn't the one on display unless tableView is the one that called it.